# Change FPC Pitch

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, connector, adapter, fpc

I recently had a PCB made with a FPC on it. Unfortunately its the wrong pitch (Yes really stupid oversight) and so we need a solution that doesn't involve ordering a new board. The board has a 4 pin 0.5mm pitch connector but the cable itself is a 4 pin 1mm pitch. I have been looking around for adapter/converter boards or cables but haven't been able to find any. Is there any way around this problem other than directly soldering the fpc to the board?

Comment: Proto advantage might have it

Comment: If you made a PCB, you should be able to make an adapter PCB pretty quick...

Comment: Did u ever get a solution to this?